# Can't access data from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

So I want to access the profile name based on the logged in user inside my react native app. The problem here is that even tho I can access the suer document i can't access the data inside it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { app, auth } from '../firebaseconfig';
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const db = getFirestore(app);

const MainPage = () => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      try {
        const user = auth.currentUser;
        console.log('current user UID is:', user.uid);
    
        if (user) {
          const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', user.uid);
          console.log('The doc is:', userDocRef);
    
          const userDocSnapshot = await getDoc(userDocRef);
          console.log('User document:', userDocSnapshot);
    
          if (userDocSnapshot) {
            console.log('User document exists:', userDocSnapshot.data());
            
            // Check if userData and userData.name exist before setting the state
            const userData = userDocSnapshot.data();
            if (userData && 'name' in userData) {
              setUserName(userData.name);
              console.log('Name property found:', userData.name);
            } else {
              console.log('Name property not found in user data');
            }
          } else {
            console.log('User document does not exist in Firestore');
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
      }
    };
    
    fetchUserData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Hello, {userName}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

export default MainPage;
```

LOGS

```
 LOG  current user UID is: 4sXptgVpAgUSh8jILHuv45R8fiz1
 LOG  The doc is: {"_key": {"path": {"len": 2, "offset": 0, "segments": [Array]}}, "converter": null, "firestore": {"app": [FirebaseAppImpl], "databaseId": [DatabaseId], "settings": [FirestoreSettingsImpl]}, "type": "document"}   
 LOG  User document: {"_converter": null, "_document": null, "_firestore": {"app": [FirebaseAppImpl], "databaseId": [DatabaseId], "settings": [FirestoreSettingsImpl]}, "_firestoreImpl": {"app": [FirebaseAppImpl], "databaseId": [DatabaseId], "settings": [FirestoreSettingsImpl]}, "_key": {"path": {"len": 2, "offset": 0, "segments": [Array]}}, "_userDataWriter": {"firestore": [Object]}, "metadata": {"fromCache": false, "hasPendingWrites": false}}
 LOG  User Data: undefined
 LOG  Name property not found in user data
```

1. Checked the Firestore rules to ensure they allow read access based on the user's UID.
2. Console Logged the code to check why can't i access the data.

Comment: try changing "name" to "displayName". as "name" is not valid property of user.

Comment: @RajendraAVerma While that'd apply to the user object from Firebase Authentication, OP is reading `name` only from data it gets from Firestore, where fields can have whatever name they choose.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `getDoc` **always** results a `DocumentSnapshot`, so this check will never fail:

```
if (userDocSnapshot) {
```

If you want to check whether the snapshot if of an existing document, call its [`exists` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot.md#documentsnapshotexists):

```
if (userDocSnapshot.exists()) {
```

This will fix the behavior, and likely show that no document exists for the user. To further troubleshoot why that is, carefully compare the path of the document you're trying to load with the actual path in the database.